# Apply scalar function to each row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a function that works like this: `select score from comparestrings(@String1,@string2)`
I need to compare every row in a table(@string2) to @string1. Is it possible without While loop and a cursor?
My function came from [simmetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) library

The code of function is below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION 
[dbo].[BlockDistance](@firstword [nvarchar](255), @secondword [nvarchar](255))
RETURNS [float] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [TextFunctions].[StringMetrics].[BlockDistance]
```

Comment: you could use CROSS APPLY and a  table valued function

Comment: Can you give a small example please? I'm doing the following:SELECT b.score
FROM MyTable a
CROSS APPLY BlockDistance ('sample text', a.SampleText) b and get: invalid object name. I found on the web that I should convert scalar function to table-valued function to get this to work, but How I actually convert that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is comparestrings a UDF that returns a table?

Instead, just make it return a `scalar value` and do this:

```
select comparestrings(@string1, tablestring) from yourtable
```

Comment: Note the response I got to my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230787/udf-performance-in-mysql) suggesting that UDF's can have performance implications.  Not sure whether this is still an issue given SQL-2008 engine?

Answer (score 1):

Don't call it row by row.

*Store it* row by row with a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) if the inputs are constants or columns from the same row.

```
ALTER TABLE Mytable ADD
    Score AS comparestrings(Col1,Col2)
```

Then you can PERSIST it and index it too

Comment: No unfortunately those are dynamic and from different tables and databases